# Is it possible to add a logo to an existing image file?

Tags: php, jquery

Is it possible to add additional image to an existing image using php or jquery?The logic is same as watermark in PHP but I want the logo to be draggable so a user can position the image anywhere on the existing image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is. You will have to:

- Set the position via javascript on front-side.
- Get the image position, server-side
- Merge the two images.

Comment: How to merge it?

Comment: is this the code for merging?
<?php
// Create image instances
$dest = imagecreatefromgif('php.gif');
$src = imagecreatefromgif('php.gif');

// Copy and merge
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 10, 0, 0, 100, 47, 75);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
imagegif($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
?>

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.imagecopymerge.php

Comment: I have the link.But what if it's png,bmp,jpeg?Can I avoid using these functions?
imagecreatefromgif
imagecreatefromjpeg
imagecreatefrompng
imagecreatefromstring
imagecreatefromwbmp
imagecreatefromxbm
imagecreatefromxpm or accept any type of image file and when it's crop the output is jpeg.